# CSS Flexbox: wrap item tile grid, specify items per row?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I have a div with 20 items:

```
       <div class="brand-illustrations">
          <img src="modules/foundation/assets/images/pb_brand_icons_01_Shipping.svg">
          <img src="modules/foundation/assets/images/pb_brand_icons_02_Time_Savings.svg">
          <img src="modules/foundation/assets/images/pb_brand_icons_03_Increase.svg">
          <img src="modules/foundation/assets/images/pb_brand_icons_04_Decrease.svg">
          <img src="modules/foundation/assets/images/pb_brand_icons_05_Money.svg">
          <img src="modules/foundation/assets/images/pb_brand_icons_06_Money_Savings.svg">
          <img src="modules/foundation/assets/images/pb_brand_icons_07_Accuracy.svg">
          ...etc...
        </div>
```

And I made the enclosing div a flexbox:

```
.brand-illustrations {
   display: flex;
   justify-content: space-between;
   flex-wrap: wrap;
   img {
     display: block;
   }
}
```

Which does as expected:
[image]

But I'd prefer to wrap to the next row after every 5th item. I know about n-th-child but am unsure the best way to use it with flex items.

Answer (score 1):

You can't *force* flexbox to wrap as it has no grid function. At best you can fix the width of each flex-item to 20% with 'flex: 0 0 20%'..but I'd suggest wrapping each image in a div as they have unexpected results under flexbox.

[**Codepen Demo**](http://codepen.io/Paulie-D/pen/wWPOYv)

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}
.box {
  flex: 0 0 20%;
  text-align: center;
  margin-bottom: 1em;
}
img {
  max-width: 100%;
  min-width: 0;
  height: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="box">
    <img src="http://placekitten.com/100/100" alt="" />
  </div>
  <div class="box">
    <img src="http://placekitten.com/100/100" alt="" />
  </div>
  <div class="box">
    <img src="http://placekitten.com/100/100" alt="" />
  </div>
  <div class="box">
    <img src="http://placekitten.com/100/100" alt="" />
  </div>
  <div class="box">
    <img src="http://placekitten.com/100/100" alt="" />
  </div>
  <div class="box">
    <img src="http://placekitten.com/100/100" alt="" />
  </div>
  <div class="box">
    <img src="http://placekitten.com/100/100" alt="" />
  </div>
  <div class="box">
    <img src="http://placekitten.com/100/100" alt="" />
  </div>
  <div class="box">
    <img src="http://placekitten.com/100/100" alt="" />
  </div>
  <div class="box">
    <img src="http://placekitten.com/100/100" alt="" />
  </div>
</div>
```